# Unable to use PG gem for existing rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

I'm trying to modify an existing Rails project, but when I run `bundle exec rails db:setup` to set up the database, I get the following error:

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: dlopen(/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-
1.4.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 0x0009): tried: 
'/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.4.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle'
 (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), 
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.
1.0/gems/pg-1.4.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle' (no such file), 
'/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.4.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle'
 (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - 
/Users/name/.rbenv/versions/3.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/pg-1.4.4/lib/pg_ext.bundle
...
```

I ran `bundle install` on the project, which installed the following:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.2'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '>= 1.0.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'pry-rails'
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

When I ran this, it did pop up 'Using pg 1.4.4' on the install, alongside a bunch of other gems. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I just faced the same issue few hours ago
try `gem uninstall pg` all versions and bundle again

Answer (score 0):

Are you using mac m1?
I think you should delete the current gem pg and bundle again to install `gem pg` for `arm`

Comment: I am using m1. I tried to uninstall gem pg and reinstall, but it's still giving me the same issue. I've also tried updating my other gems, which didn't help.

Comment: 1. make sure you have installed `pg` and started pg service.
2. try to install gem via: 

`brew install libpq`

`export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"`

`gem install pg`

Comment: So it still was giving me the same error. What I ended up doing was changing my platform to x-84_64-darwin instead of arm (changed ```ruby 3.1.0p0 (2021-12-25 revision fb4df44d16) [arm64-darwin21]``` to ```ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin21]```) and then running ```bundle install```. It was finally able to create and seed the db.